# Remove div block and replace it by another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a js code that suppose to remove block1 and replace it with block2 by an onclick function

```
function buyerclick() {
  div = document.getElementById('block2');
  div.style.display = "block";
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('block1');
  elem.parentNode.remove(elem);
}
```

Block2 is working OK but block1 isn't remove it just stayed under block2. What I did wrong? I need that block1 removed with all its elements.

Comment: Are you using JQuery or not ? The code you provided is plain JS.

Comment: You used the function getElementsByClassName, which will return an array. So either you have to do elem[0] or replace it with getElementById like you did in your first one

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *within the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getElementsByClassName returns a collection, so you have to change that line to:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('block1')[0];
```

Comment: I chandeg it, but now while I use onclick it just clear all content from html page

Comment: You should use removechild for this: elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);